# How to test a connected component wrapped in another connected component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

I want to test my pure component so I'm doing this:

MyComp.js

```
export MyComp = props => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>Content</Wrapper>
  )
}

const MyCompConn = connect()(MyComp);
export default MyCompConn;
```

Where `<Wrapper>`:

```
export Wrapper = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div>{children}</div>
  )
}

const WrapperConn = connect()(Wrapper);
export default WrapperConn;
```

MyComp.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import { MyComp } from '../../MyComp';


describe('With Snapshot Testing', () => {
  it('renders!"', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(<Login />);
    const tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Now, when I run `yarn test` I get this error:

`Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(AppWrapper)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider> or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(AppWrapper)"`

And this is happening because `<Wrapper>` is connected in my `<MyComp>` component, but I'm not sure how to test **just** the latter even if it's wrapped on a connected component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To test our component without using mocked store, we can mock the connect of react-redux itself using Jest. PFB the example:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import { MyComp } from '../../MyComp';

jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  connect: () => {
    return (component) => {
      return component
    };
  }
}));

describe('With Snapshot Testing', () => {
  it('renders!"', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(<Login />);
    const tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Now, this will render the `Wrapper` component directly, and not the `connected Wrapper` component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';

const store = mockStore({});
const component = renderer.create(<Provider store={store}><Login /></Provider>);
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without the mocked store?

Comment: also, this doesn't work, I get `TypeError: store.getState is not a function`